# Is it possible to compute values using data from rows in a cascading fashion in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the data in my table. I need to compute the difference between `MINMAXPOINTS` from every next row for a specific position and if positive, record output as 1 and if negative, record output as 0 and then sum up all the output values into a locally declared variable.

```
Id  Date    Position    MINMAXPOINTS
1   1/11/2016   ABOVE   82.4
2   1/5/2016    ABOVE   81.75
3   12/1/2015   ABOVE   72.79
4   10/28/2015  ABOVE   76.7
5   10/20/2015  ABOVE   80
6   1/15/2016   BELOW   68.4
7   1/7/2016    BELOW   72.29
8   12/14/2015  BELOW   61.25
9   11/10/2015  BELOW   60.89
10  10/27/2015  BELOW   73.29
11  9/4/2015    BELOW   54.35
```

The above data has been `PARTITION`ed by `Position` and then `ORDER`ed by `Date DESC`.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTE_MinMax.Position ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS MINMAXPOINTS
```

So the algorithm would be something like:

- Compute sum of differences of `MINMAXPOINTS` for every next row like:
  (1-2) + (2-3) + (3-4) + (4-5) for `'ABOVE'` and 
  (6-7) + (7-8) + (8-9) + (9-10) + (10-11) for `'BELOW'`.
- Depending on the sign of each number from differences above, we get: 
  (1) + (1) + (-1) + (-1) for `'ABOVE'` and  (-1) + (1) + (1) + (-1) +
  (1) for `'BELOW'`
- Next, we total all the values for `'ABOVE'` and `'BELOW'` and store `1`
  as the grand total in a locally declared variable.

In the above scenario the number of subtractions should be configurable. So, if i input 2, then only 2 pairs of `Positions` should be summed up like below:

(1-2) + (2-3) for `'ABOVE'` and 
(6-7) + (7-8) for `'BELOW'`

Resulting in a grand total of `3`.

It'd be totally awesome if this could be achieved just using - `WITH CTEs` or something without the use of cursors or without creation of any tables if possible.

Any help will be appreciated!.

Comment: what's your version of SQL-server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008, 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )

Comment: Sample results would help explain what you are trying to do, particularly the part about "the number of subtractions should be configurable".  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @zapper your SSMS version doesn't matter for this. What matters is the version of SQL Server. Run this: `select @@version` and report back.

Comment: @Gordon, i've included a sample in the question itself. So, if we want 3 pairs of Positions to be subtracted, then differences between the 1st and 2nd rows + differences between 2nd and 3rd row + differences between 3rd and 4th rows of 'ABOVE' and differences between the 1st and 2nd rows + differences between 2nd and 3rd row + differences between 3rd and 4th rows of 'BELOW' should be computed for the column MINMAXPOINTS and then summed up.

Comment: @alroc, I got this: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86)   Jul  9 2008 14:43:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.1 <X86> (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Comment: We can achieve it through CROSS APPLY querry

Comment: Sounds like you could apply a running total technique here.   Google `how to do a running total in SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH temp
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Position, Date) AS srn 
    FROM Table1 
), 
temp1
AS
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position ORDER BY srn) AS srn1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.*, (t1.MINMAXPOINTS - t2.MINMAXPOINTS) AS Diff
        FROM temp t1 
        LEFT JOIN temp t2
        ON t1.srn = t2.srn - 1 AND t1.Position = t2.Position    
    )t
)
SELECT Position, SUM(Diff)
FROM temp1
WHERE 
srn1 <= 2 -- 3, 4 any number upto which you need to calculate total
GROUP BY Position
```